# Set the handler of lambda in AWS Console (web)

Tags: aws-lambda

I was used to being able to enter the handler details in the AWS Console: [image: selection of handler]

But now this bar is missing:
[image: no selection available]

I can enter the route to the handler using AWS-CLI, but for the sake of quicker tests, how do I get the input for handler selection back?

Comment: There should be a "Basic Settings" block lower on the page with an "edit" button, that includes the Handler

Comment: so easy and yet i didn't notice! Thanks :)